# BCEWithLogitsLoss in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

How to implement `BCEWithLogitsLoss` in keras and use it as custom loss function while using `Tensorflow` as backend.

I have used `BCEWithLogitsLoss` in `PyTorch` which was defined in `torch`.

How to implement the same in Keras.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TensorFlow, you can directly call [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) which works both in TensorFlow 1.x and 2.0.

If you want to stick to Keras API, use [`tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) and set `from_logits=True` in the constructor call.

Unlike PyTorch, there are not explicit per-example weights in the API. You can instead set `reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` for the loss, do your weighting by explicit multiplication and reduce your loss using `tf.reduce_mean`.

```py
xent = tf.losses.BinaryCrossEntropy(
    from_logits=True,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent(targets, pred) * weights))
```

Comment: Actually, I want to do something like this `def custom_loss(data, targets):

    bce_loss_1 = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=targets[:,1:2])(data[:,:1],targets[:,:1])
    bce_loss_2 = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(data[:,1:],targets[:,2:])
    return (bce_loss_1 * loss_weight) + bce_loss_2 `

Comment: Keras losses don't have explicit weight as PyTorch does. What you can do set `reduction='NONE'` in the loss construction, so the losses don't get summed or averaged in the batch, apply your weights and reduces the per-example losses explicitly with `tf.reduce_mean`.

Comment: Can you show the usage of the same in the answer with the help of a toy example.?

Comment: `xent = tf.losses.BinaryCrossEntropy(from_logits=True, reduction='NONE');
def custom_loss(data, targets, weights): return tf.reduce_mean(xent(targets[:,:1], data[:,:1]) * weights) + tf.reduce_mean(targets[:,2:], xent(data[:,1:]))`

Comment: I am getting a `ValueError` with `Invalid Reduction Key NONE`

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE`